# Understanding Python3 stdout buffering to pipe

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

I'm having trouble understanding why the print statement in the code produces output immediately.

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python3', '-i'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
_ = proc.stdin.write(b'2+2\n')
_ = proc.stdin.flush()
print(proc.stdout.readline())
# produces b'4\n' immidiately!
proc.terminate()
proc.wait(timeout=0.2)
```

Shouldn't the child 'python -i''s stdout be fully buffered as it is writing to a pipe?
Meaning, I should not see the output in the print statement until the child terminates, or the child's stdout buffer becomes full and is explicitly flushed to the os?

Interesting, the same behavior on the terminal- output seen after an 'enter'. Perhaps 'python -i' flushes output after a '\n'?

````
➜  ~ python3 -i -c 'print("hiiiii")' | cat 
>>> 
>>> hiiiii

>>> ^D```
````

Comment: Tangential to the question, but rather than assign the return values of the `write` and `flush` calls to `_`, you could just ignore them completely.

Comment: right, didn't want to clutter my output on the (parent) interpreter

Comment: Ah okay, sorry, didn't realise you were running these interactively.

Comment: Incidentally, in your last example, it seems that if you press return that is also enough to see the `hiiiiii` output.

Comment: That's interesting! I think I'm hitting the behavior of python interpreter.. perhaps it flushes right after an 'enter'?

Comment: Modified the question with the updated behavior you noticed

Comment: @alaniwi: FYI, folks often assign return values to `_` to indicate they know there is one, but aren't interested in its value (and it's not a mistake).

Comment: @martineau Fair enough. I'd more come across it in contexts where the value can't simply be ignored -- e.g. you are unpacking a tuple but are only interested in some of the values, or a dummy `for` loop variable.